# Problem with website deployment in angular on AWS ec2

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

I have zipped and uploaded all my code files on the AWS ec2 instance and also configured the corresponding DNS on my godaddy account, but my website is still not getting deployed.

Also I have tried deploying it on aws s3 and Elastic beanstalk as well, but it is still not working. The same files, however, work on my local server.

Also doing an ng build on my EC2 virtual server gives me these errors.
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

> Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
>       at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:44:19)
>       at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:31:21)
>       at BuildCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:189:32)
>       at BuildCommand. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:55:25)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:14:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:10:12)
>       at BuildCommand.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:54:16)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:101:23)

Please help. I am new to this.

Comment: Okay. Do you try npm install on S3 bucket? I think some files not installed properly.

Comment: @Artem Arkhipov: yes, I tried doing that . still did not work.